# Generating a random color for the left border of multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been at this for two hours and i did not find a solution.
So dont say that this question has already been answered, as this is somewhat different to generating random color for one element.
Anyway, this part of my code is not working:

```html
<script>
  function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
  }

  function setRandomBorderColor() {
        var i;
        var contentbox = document.getElementsByClassName(".content-box");
        for (var i=0; i = contentbox.length; i++){
          contentbox[i].css("border-left-color", getRandomColor());
        };
  }
  </script>
```

I would be so thankful if someone can help me!

Comment: Are you using a class name with a dot (`".content-box"`) or is it a typo in `document.getElementsByClassName(".content-box")`?

Comment: `function getRandomColor() { return "#" + ((Math.random() * 0x1000000) | 0x1000000).toString(16).slice(1); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tagged this question with jquery, but appear to be using *mostly* pure javascript. I've provided a jquery solution below (which is a bit shorter code wise) but also a working javascript solution if you need it. At the moment you're combining jquery selectors and styling commands with javascript selected elements (which won't work!).

---

## JQuery Solution

The code below acts as you would like, it uses jquery to iterate over each of the divs with class `.content-box` and assign a random colour using your generator. It is a little simpler than the pure javascript code version below.

```js
// Set initial colours
setRandomBorderColor();


// Change colours if button clicked
$("#changeColor").click(function() {
  setRandomBorderColorPureJS();
});


//  Assign random colours to all .content-box elements
function setRandomBorderColor() {

  $(".content-box").each(function() {

    $(this).css("border-left-color", getRandomColor());

  });

};


// Generate random colour
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="changeColor">Change Colours</button>

<div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
</div>
```

---

## Pure Javascript

This version has no need for jquery. You made a few mistakes:

- `document.getElementsByClassName(".content-box");` - this should **not** have a preceding `.` before the class name as javascript is already expecting a class name, you are using jquery notation here where the jquery selector can take an `id`, `class`, etc and so you need to tell it which.
- `for (var i=0; i = contentbox.length; i++)` - you should not use the '=' operator here, but '<' as you have in your color generator. If you use '=' then you try to act upon a non-existent DOM element and the code fails.

A few warnings, in this version of the code I have taken out any need for jquery, which would include these lines:

- `contentbox[i].css("border-left-color", getRandomColor())` (jquery) -> `contentbox[i].style.borderLeftColor =  getRandomColor();` (pure javascript)
- `$("#changeColor").click(function() { setRandomBorderColorPureJS();});` (jquery) -> `document.getElementById("changeColor").addEventListener("click", setRandomBorderColor);` (javascript)

```js
// Set initial colours
setRandomBorderColor();


// Change colours if button clicked
document.getElementById("changeColor").addEventListener("click", setRandomBorderColor);


//  Assign random colours to all .content-box elements
function setRandomBorderColor() {
  var contentbox = document.getElementsByClassName("content-box");
  for (var i = 0; i < contentbox.length; i++) {
    contentbox[i].style.borderLeftColor = getRandomColor();
  };
}


// Generate random colour
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```css
.content-box {
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button id="changeColor">Change Colours</button>

<div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
  <div class="content-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still does not work. i just dont know what.. but thanks anyway for the help

Comment: Updated, let me know if that helps

Comment: oh, now it works apparently. i also discovered my error and i fixed everything .thanks a lot!

Comment: The last thing is that this doesn't create a border if it doesn't already exist, just changes the color of an existing one. Make sure you have set border-left: 2px solid black; within the styling for.content-box

Answer (score 2):

There are few of mistakes in your code.

1. `document.getElementsByClassName()` accepts just a class name as an argument, without a dot. So it should be `document.getElementsByClassName('content-box')`.
2. In your `for` loop condition you have to write `i < contentbox.length` instead of `i = contentbox.length`. Check out the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for.
3. You can't call `css()` function on native DOM elements (which you get from `document.getElementsByClassName()` function). To change a CSS property of a native DOM element you should use `contentbox[i].style.borderLeftColor = getRandomColor()` ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)). If you want to use `.css()`, you should use jQuery.
4. You declare your `i` variable twice (before the loop and inside of the loop condition). It doesn't cause any error, but you just don't need to do that.

So your code should look like this:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }

  return color;
}

function setRandomBorderColor() {
  var contentbox = document.getElementsByClassName("content-box");

  for (var i = 0; i < contentbox.length; i++) {
    contentbox[i].style.borderLeftColor = getRandomColor();
  }
}
```

To make your code actually work, don't forget to call the `setRandomBorderColor()` after your document DOM is ready, and also set some `border-left-width` and `border-left-style` for your elements. If you set only border color, you won't see any border.